# Android accelerometer sensitivity programming

Tags: android

Can anyone please help me how to decrease the sensitivity of the accelerometer on an android device?

Comment: Why do you need to change it? Can't you just scale the values in the SensorEvent according to your requirements?

Comment: I'm getting too many values. I use accelerometer to move in an application. When i tilt the device a very little the object moves very fast. So wanted to reduce it.

Comment: Have you looked at: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/AccelerometerPlay/src/com/example/android/accelerometerplay/AccelerometerPlayActivity.html, specifically this line: mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);

Comment: Ya. I used the one which gives max delay which is SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL. But still its too much sensitive.

Comment: So if there is any other way please help me regarding it?

Comment: Why not just filter the event if the acceleration values are not greater than your application-specific threshold?

Comment: I think you can't. I would use SENSOR_DELAY_UI with a timer with a delay of 1 second or what you want.

Comment: My objects next position directly depends on the value given from the sensors. So specifying threshold will cause it to move very fast or it just disappear and reappear which will be very odd to look.

Answer (score 3):

You should implement a high pass filter to filter out high frequencies. Which will smooth out the values.

Check out the [Android Sensor event docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html)

Comment: Can you help me with that? Plz let me know how do we implement it on AccelerometerPlay demo api given in the android sdk?

Comment: Thank You very much. I got the solution by implementing the high pass filter. Thanks for all the help guys.